# nx_altair - TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, typeerror, networkx, graph-theory, graph-visualization

I'm trying to visualize the network graphs using `nx_altair` is a library for drawing NetworkX graphs using Altair. It offers a similar draw API as `NetworkX` but returns `Altair Charts` instead.

Started using basic [tutorials](https://github.com/Zsailer/nx_altair/blob/master/examples/nx_altair-tutorial.ipynb) from the package.

```
import networkx as nx
import nx_altair as nxa


sub_g = nx.ego_graph(G=GE3, n=1405394338)
pos_g = nx.spring_layout(sub_g)
```

Nodes data

```
sub_g.nodes(data=True)
```

```
NodeDataView({1405394338: {}, 1354581834: {}, 1334448011: {}, 1367797753: {}, 1244950426: {}})
```

Edge data

```
sub_g.edges(data=True)
```

```
EdgeDataView([(1405394338, 1367797753, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM', 'Phone':
5392353776, 'VIN': '1C3CDZBG9DN5907'}), (1405394338, 1334448011, {'Email':
'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM', 'Phone': 5392353776}), (1405394338, 1244950426, {'Email':
'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'}), (1405394338, 1354581834, {'Phone': 5392353776}), (1354581834,
1367797753, {'Phone': 5392353776}), (1354581834, 1334448011, {'Phone': 5392353776}), (1334448011,
1367797753, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM', 'Phone': 5392353776}), (1334448011,
1244950426, {'Email': 'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'}), (1367797753, 1244950426, {'Email':
'NJOHNSONJOHNSON34@GMAIL.COM'})])
```

I'm able to plot the network using the `nx.draw_network()`

```
nx.draw_networkx(
    G=sub_g,
    pos=pos_g,
)
```

[image]

When I'm trying to plot the same network using `nx_altair` it is throwing me an error with TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

```
nxa.draw_networkx(
    G=sub_g,
    pos=pos_g,
)
```

Below is the complete error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py in to_dict(self, *args, **kwargs)
    371 
    372         try:
--> 373             dct = super(TopLevelMixin, copy).to_dict(*args, **kwargs)
    374         except jsonschema.ValidationError:
    375             dct = None

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py in to_dict(self, validate, ignore, context)
    326                 {k: v for k, v in self._kwds.items() if k not in ignore},
    327                 validate=sub_validate,
--> 328                 context=context,
    329             )
    330         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py in _todict(obj, validate, context)
     60         return {
     61             k: _todict(v, validate, context)
---> 62             for k, v in obj.items()
     63             if v is not Undefined
     64         }

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
     61             k: _todict(v, validate, context)
     62             for k, v in obj.items()
---> 63             if v is not Undefined
     64         }
     65     elif hasattr(obj, "to_dict"):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py in _todict(obj, validate, context)
     56         return obj.to_dict(validate=validate, context=context)
     57     elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
---> 58         return [_todict(v, validate, context) for v in obj]
     59     elif isinstance(obj, dict):
     60         return {

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     56         return obj.to_dict(validate=validate, context=context)
     57     elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
---> 58         return [_todict(v, validate, context) for v in obj]
     59     elif isinstance(obj, dict):
     60         return {

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/utils/schemapi.py in _todict(obj, validate, context)
     54     """Convert an object to a dict representation."""
     55     if isinstance(obj, SchemaBase):
---> 56         return obj.to_dict(validate=validate, context=context)
     57     elif isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, np.ndarray)):
     58         return [_todict(v, validate, context) for v in obj]

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py in to_dict(self, *args, **kwargs)
    361         copy = self.copy(deep=False)
    362         original_data = getattr(copy, "data", Undefined)
--> 363         copy.data = _prepare_data(original_data, context)
    364 
    365         if original_data is not Undefined:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py in _prepare_data(data, context)
     90     # consolidate inline data to top-level datasets
     91     if context is not None and data_transformers.consolidate_datasets:
---> 92         data = _consolidate_data(data, context)
     93 
     94     # if data is still not a recognized type, then return

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py in _consolidate_data(data, context)
     57 
     58     if values is not Undefined:
---> 59         name = _dataset_name(values)
     60         data = core.NamedData(name=name, **kwds)
     61         context.setdefault("datasets", {})[name] = values

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/altair/vegalite/v4/api.py in _dataset_name(values)
     33     if isinstance(values, core.InlineDataset):
     34         values = values.to_dict()
---> 35     values_json = json.dumps(values, sort_keys=True)
     36     hsh = hashlib.md5(values_json.encode()).hexdigest()
     37     return "data-" + hsh

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

/usr/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: I don't know the `nx_altair` library, but you could try turning your node ids to integers and use labels (which probably don't need to be hashable and can be any string).

Comment: How can I turn my node ids to integers?

Comment: Using the [`convert_node_labels_to_integers`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html#networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers)

Comment: But this labels my nodes, how can I retain my original node values.

Comment: `draw_networkx` has a parameter `labels`, if your used package mimics that, it also should have this parameters. The information in labels will then be printed instead of the node ids.

Comment: Other alternative is to replace the `int64` with `strings`

Comment: Can it be possible to replace int64 with strings?

Comment: You could try [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html)`(sub_G, {node:str(node) for node in sub_G})`

Comment: Tried with this 
`mapping = {node:str(node) for node in sub_g}`
`H = nx.relabel_nodes(sub_g, mapping)`
and passed `H`...

No luck. I'm still getting the same error

Comment: That's unexpected. Not sure if you have other int64 in your graph. Probably you've run into a quite old bug/problem with json and int64, see e.g. https://bugs.python.org/issue24313

Comment: Could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/68273575/14045537

Comment: Graph type conversion is happening in the function, not sure where and how to fix that